# navigator.contacts.find does neither call onSucess nor onError

Tags: mobile, contacts, navigator

I call the getcontacts function twice. First when I start the app and a second time (just for testing) in a subpage. Both don't work. It doesn't call the OnSuccess or the onError because no alert is shown.

My header :

```
        <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=deviceWidth; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
    <title>Blabla</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/phonegap.js"></script>

<!-- Finde Kontakte-->

    var phone_contacts;

    function getContacts() {

        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        // Falls Filter gwünscht        
        options.filter=""; 
        options.multiple=true; 

        var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
        //alert('this alert is shown');
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessContacts, onErrorContacts, options);
        alert('this alert isn't shown');

    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccessContacts(contacts) {
        alert('Sucess');//is not shown

        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
           //Speicherung in Debugging Konsole
           // console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);

           //Kontakte nach Laden in globale Variable phone_contacts übetragen
           phone_contacts = contacts[i];

           //Speicherung der Kontakte in <p id="show_contacts">
           var element_contacts = document.getElementById('show_contacts');
        element.innerHTML += contacts[i].displayName;
        }
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onErrorContacts(contactError) {
            alert('Error');//isn't shown
        alert('onError!');
    }

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', doDeviceReady, false);

    function doDeviceReady () {
        // The following tells the app to fade #page1 in after the splash screen
        //get contacts
        getContacts();

        $('#page1').fadeIn(5000);

    }

});
    </script>
<!-- eof Finde Kontakte-->

</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
alert('this alert isn't shown');
```

to

```
alert('this alert isn\'t shown');
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the opening `<script>` tag in this page?

Comment: Actualy there is a geolocation function above it. So I cut out to much in this example. The script tag is there in my code. I'm sorry about making a wrong post. But under the assumption there is everything there  has to be another error?